# Iframe not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, iframe

I'm struggling to get my iframe working, i used this code in a previous one that worked but this url doesn't seem to be working. Please help.

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto; max-width: 1181px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://solid.vox.co.za/vox/portal/public/services/ftth/viewFtthMap" style="border: 0px none; height: 200px; margin-top: 0px; width: 1583px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you have provided is not working without login. You will need to host the link on a public URL like google drive, YouTube or any other public domain and make sure you can open the URL without any session.

The best way of doing this is checking the URL in a new incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not working (or not working without a valid logged-in session). The iframe is fine. Make sure to provide a valid URL.